# Finding items that occur exactly once in an array

Tags: python, arrays, tuples, python-2.7

I have an 2 dimensional array.  Each of the row vectors, in this case, is considered a quantity of interest.  What I want to do is return all the rows that appear *exactly once* as one array, and all the rows that appear more than once as a second array.

For example, if the array was:

```
a=[[1,1,1,0], [1,1,1,0], [5,1,6,0], [3,2,1,0], [4,4,1,0], [5,1,6,0]]
```

I would like to return two arrays:

```
nonsingles=[[1,1,1,0], [1,1,1,0], [5,1,6,0], [5,1,6,0]]
singles= [[3,2,1,0], [4,4,1,0]]
```

It is important that the order stay preserved.  The code I have written to do this is as follows:

```
def singles_nonsingles(array):
#returns the elements that occur only once, and the elements
#that occur more than once in the array
singles=[]
nonsingles=[]
arrayhash=map(tuple, array)

for x in arrayhash:
    if (arrayhash.count(x)==1):
        singles.append(x)

    if (arrayhash.count(x)>1):
        nonsingles.append(x)

nonsingles=array(nonsingles)
singles=array(singles)

return {'singles':singles, 'nonsingles':nonsingles}
```

Now, I am happy to say that this works, but unhappy to say that it is extremely slow, as a typical array i have is 30000(rows)x10 elements/row=300000 elements.  Can anyone give me some tips about how to speed this up??  I apologize if this question is very simple, I am new to Python.  Also, I am using Numpy/Scipy with Python 2.7, if that is any help.

Comment: Do you need to include all the duplicates in `nonsingles`? Would it not be enough to return `=[[1,1,1,0], [5,1,6,0]]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2.7 or above, you can use `collections.Counter` to count the number of occurrences:

```
def unique_items(iterable):
    tuples = map(tuple, iterable)
    counts = collections.Counter(tuples)
    unique = []
    non_unique = []
    for t in tuples:
        if counts[t] == 1:
            unique.append(t)
        else:
            non_unique.append(t)
    return unique, non_unique
```

Comment: Thanks Sven!  That was way faster.  I'm not totally clear why that is, though.  It seems that we are both implementing one loop, that does a similar test on the data.  Can you explain why it's so much faster, just for curiosity's sake??  How is the counter implemented, if not with a loop itself?

Comment: This doesn't work in python 3.2. As map returns an iterator you consume the iterator when counting.

Comment: You could wrap the call to `map()` in a call to `list()`, or use a list comprehension:  `tuples = [tuple(x) for x in iterable]`

Comment: @Mike, as I explained in my answer, your problem was that you were doing an `in` test on a `list`.  This has time complexity of O(n) where n is the number of items in the list, so the bigger the list the slower it gets.  A `collections.Counter()` is basically a `dict`, and either one looks things up in O(1) time (it takes pretty much the same amount of time to look something up no matter how many  items are in the data structure).

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you are doing an `in` test on a `list`.  This has O(n) performance.

It should be faster to build a `dict` and then use that to figure out what to do with each row.

EDIT: The code had an unnecessary `enumerate()` in it; I stripped it out.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def singles_nonsingles(array):
    #returns the elements that occur only once, and the elements
    #that occur more than once in the array
    singles=[]
    nonsingles=[]
    d = defaultdict(int)

    t = [tuple(row) for row in array]

    for row in t:
        d[row] += 1

    for row in t:
        if d[row] == 1:
            singles.append(row)
        else:
            nonsingles.append(row)

    return {'singles':singles, 'nonsingles':nonsingles}
```

Here's a version that only returns unique rows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def singles_nonsingles(array):
    #returns the elements that occur only once, and the elements
    #that occur more than once in the array
    singles=[]
    nonsingles=[]
    d = defaultdict(int)
    already_seen = set()

    t = [tuple(row) for row in array]

    for row in t:
        d[row] += 1

    for row in t:
        if row in already_seen:
            continue
        if d[row] == 1:
            singles.append(row)
        else:
            nonsingles.append(row)
        already_seen.add(row)

    return {'singles':singles, 'nonsingles':nonsingles}


a=[[1,1,1,0], [1,1,1,0], [5,1,6,0], [3,2,1,0], [4,4,1,0], [5,1,6,0]]

x = singles_nonsingles(a)
print("Array: " + str(a))
print(x)
```

Comment: You should turn rows into tuples as you loop over `array`, rather than creating `t`.  This would require much less memory, since there's no need to have both `array` and `t` in memory at the same time.  This would also eliminate the need for the confusing `enumerate` in the second loop.

Comment: @AaronDufour, I'm not sure I agree.  Nothing we do inside this function will free `array`, so the only question is how much memory we will use inside the function.  We could probably rewrite this so that we don't need to build `t`, which would free some memory. (We will save references to tuples of unique rows in `d`, while `t` contains every tuples of every `row`.  By not building `t` we would avoid saving the duplicate `row` tuples.)  Finally, I'm not sure why you find the `enumerate()` confusing as it is the usual Python idiom for getting indices along with values.

Comment: I must admit that the `enumerate()` just wasn't needed.  All I was doing was using it to lookup the current row, but the current row is always available as `row` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The first return only the list of the single/no single arrays without repetitions, the second with repetitions

```
def comp (multi):
    from collections import defaultdict

    res = defaultdict(int)

    for vect in multi:
        res[tuple(vect)] += 1

    singles = []
    no_singles = []

    for k in res:
        if res[k] > 1:
            no_singles.append(list(k))
        elif res[k] == 1:
            singles.append(list(k))

    return singles, no_singles

def count_w_repetitions(multi):
    from collections import defaultdict

    res = defaultdict(int)

    for vect in multi:
        res[tuple(vect)] += 1

    singles = []
    no_singles = []

    for k in res:
        if res[k] == 1:
            singles.append(list(k))
        else:
            for i in xrange(res[k]):
                no_singles.append(list(k))


    return singles, no_singles
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import compress,imap

def has_all_unique(a):
   return len(a) == len(frozenset(a)) 

uniq = map( has_all_unique,a)
singles = list(compress(a,uniq))
notuniq = imap(lambda x: not x,uniq)
nonsingles = list(compress(a,notuniq))
```